# A meaningful field name for the ternary relation between program, data, and result?

Tags: alloy

I have a signature for representing software programs:

```
sig Program {
    ???: Data -> Result
}
```

Each program maps input data to output result. So, there is a ternary relation (Program -> Data -> Result).

Notice the question marks for the field name. What field name do you suggest?

The name IO seems nice:

```
sig Program {
    IO: Data -> Result
}
```

Then I can write elegant expressions such as:

```
all p: Program | p.IO ...
```

However, the name IO is meaningful only for (Data -> Result) not (Program -> Data -> Result).

I am stuck. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, fields' names are most of the time contextual to the signature they are declared in, and that's really a fine thing.

If you look at a random sample module in Alloy, (e.g. `module examples/puzzle/farmer`), you'll see that it's not always that fields have meaning outside of their respective signatures:

```
sig State {
   near: set Object,
   far: set Object
}
```

Here, near and far don't really convey hints on their "temporal" nature.

Long story short, I'd stick to **io** for conciseness sake.

Indeed, I prefer the names of  :

- fiels, facts, preds, asserts, parameters, .. to be in lowercase
- signatures to be Capitalized
- enumeration (outer let), and singleton signatures to be in UPPERCASE